# Jenkins kubernetes with google cloud kubectl not found

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I followed this tutorial : https://cloud.google.com/solutions/configuring-jenkins-container-engine

But when my job run, I got

```
kubectl: not found
```

My slave are running

> Running on jnlp-slave-d8faf62bf22c in
>   /home/jenkins/workspace/k8s_symfony_master-HZ7SATWV7476573CS6I3WV3262VOLZDL4KE2TDMAG4ILA4UCBMWQ

My slave dockerfile :

```
FROM jenkinsci/jnlp-slave
MAINTAINER Vic Iglesias <viglesias@google.com>
ENV CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS 1
ENV PATH /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH
USER root
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y jq
RUN curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash && mv google-cloud-sdk /opt
RUN gcloud components install kubectl
```

And my config jenkins :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even if you set PATH in your image, that may not carry into your slave once running. Try adding an environment variable "PATH+GCLOUD=/opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin" to the slave, or even better: create a custom tool installer for gcloud+kubectl.